# Merging when someone else has pushed rebased code?

Tags: git

I have un-pushed commits locally. Someone else has pushed code to the repo that has been rebased since I pulled. Is it safe for me to push and pull normally?

Comment: Well this depends. Did the other person pushed rebased code of a existing already pushed branch you also have locally?

Comment: Can you show us the state of your local and remote branch after the questionable rebase?

Comment: @ckruczek Yes thats correct.

Comment: “un-pushed commits locally” what do you mean with that?

Comment: I mean that I have made commits locally but none of these have yet been pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote repo has a changed history (because of a rebase forced pushed), that means your repo, after a git fetch, will look like this:

```
        Z--Z--Z (new rebased origin/master)
       /
x--x--x--x--y--y (master with local unpushed commits 'y')
          \
           X--X (old origin/master)
```

The goal is to memorize your local commits, reset your master on the new origin/master and rebase your local commits:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git branch tmp
git reset --hard origin/master



x--x--x--Z--Z--Z (master, reset to new rebased origin/master)
       \
        x--y--y (tmp with local unpushed commits 'y')
```

And now rebase:

```
git checkout tmp
git rebase origin/master
git checkout master
git merge tmp
git branch -d tmp

x--x--x--Z--Z--Z--x'--y'--y' (master, on top of origin/master)
```

Then, you can push/pull normally.

Answer (score 1):

Git will prevent you to push your files and it will let you know your files are not up to date, you can then do

```
git pull --rebase <remote> <branch>
```

you might have to resolve conflicts before you can push your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull and then do the merge. Afterwards you push.
You can only push when your local files are up-to-date.